# Populating data into Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import

I am a front-end developer and have been asked to explore the possibility of automating some reports by importing SQL queries into an Excel spreadsheet.

Is this a complicated process, or something one could do by following a set of procedures?

Can someone point me in the direction of straightforward procedures?

Comment: A few more details might help - who would be the intended audience/users for the process?  How user-friendly would it need to be? Does it need to be able to run on random desktops, or just in a single location?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with **SQL Server Management Studio** you can do this. Run a query, right click on the result tab, click on `Copy or Copy with Headers` then simply go to an Excel file and paste the results onto the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy to connect Excel to SQL Server : just click on the menu

```
Data / External data / Other sources / SQL Server
```

Then enter your server name and select the database and table of your choice.

You can then use the `Refresh` command whenever your datbase changed

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to sql from excel itself. In data-->from other sources-->from sql server, connect to your server and provide database and tables there and choose table option there. You will get necessary data there.

Regards,
Julie